# Convert JSON naming schema in Ember

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have an application where I retrieve JSON data from a server. Unfortunately the JSON data is formatted as such:

```
"Product_Group" : [
        {
            "Product_Group_ID" : "396xx",
            "Product_Group_SEO_Copy" : "Not Included in JSON",
            "Product_Group_Title" : "Some awesome Title",
            "Products" : [
                {
                    "On_Sale_Date" : "04\/28\/09 00:00:00.000",
                    "ISBN" : "97800617737xx",    
                    "Title" : "A Disgraceful Affair",
//rest of the it follows
```

Ember throws errors when trying to use Capitalized JSON objects in a template. Specifically the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unchain' of undefined` error. This is related to this [issue noted on the Github Ember site](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2031).

My question, how can I convert all the titles from the server into camelCase? I don't have access to the server to change things on that end, so it will have to be client side. I've looked into the `DS.RESTSerializer` but I don't understand it enough to know if that is what I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

DS.RESTSerializer is exactly what you want to use. You can easily transform the keys of your attributes by using the [keyForAttribute](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_across-the-board-normalization) hook. You may also need to change the attribute name of your root node `Product_Group` to something like `productGroup`. You can do this with [extractArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_across-the-board-normalization).

A serializer such as this might just do the trick:

```
App.ProductGroupSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    return this._super(store, type, {
      productGroup: payload['Product_Group']
    });
  },
  keyForAttribute: function(attr) {
    return Ember.String.camelize(attr);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I can't seem to get it to actually fire. Throwing some `console.log`s in there doesn't seem to show anything. I changed it to `App.ApplicationSerializer` to run it all the time and that doesn't help either. I have the model set by calling the model method in the route function after getting it via AJAX. Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Yes, this assumes you're using Ember Data which means you're using `this.store` to access your API. If you're not using Ember Data, you will need to unserialize your data manually, but that shouldn't be too hard. You pretty much just need to camelize the hash keys of your JSON data.